# Can not import pandas in django though it is installed

Tags: django, pandas

I have installed pandas version 1.0.3 with Django. whenever I try to import pandas it gives me an error like `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'fromisocalendar'` django . how can i fix this? my python version is 3.8.

Comment: `fromisocalendar` was added in Python-3.8. Are you sure you are running this with the correct version?

Comment: What if you run `pip3 install --user --upgrade datetime`?

Comment: where should i run this command?

Comment: in a shell, activating the virtual environment.

Comment: tried but did not work! i am badly in need of help!

Comment: hey imtinan, could you please show us where and how you are importing pandas inside with file

Comment: dear Farhani, i am importing pandas as pd at the top of views.py of my app.

Comment: solved the issue changing the environment!